# How to get default compile-time value of Auto-Implemented property C# 6.0 after it changed?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, default-value, c#-6.0

**Shortly, The new C# 6.0 Auto-Implemented Property allows us to make this**

```
    public static bool IsSoundEffects { get; set; } = true;   // C# 6.0 allows this
```

Now in somewhere, I changed the property `IsSoundEffects = false`, So accessing it will be false.

hmm, So how to get the actual real default compile-time auto-implemented property value.

Something Like :
 `Type.GetPropertyDefaultValue(IsSoundEffects);`    // A real compile-time one = 
 true

OR

```
default(IsSoundEffects)   // idk, something like that
```

> Why I need that?

*because I filling the properties from the database. and restore it if user need to restore the default values. for example settings.*

**Looks strange?** I searched enough but all examples about the auto-implemented feature did not restore the default value.

**Edited**

The best approaches provided by

> **xiangbin.pang** answer for reflection way *[Short-One]*
>
> **Christopher** answers for constants as default values.

Comment: If you really wanted to *muck-around*, create a *custom attribute*, and in-turn take the hit from *reflection*, this will have a flow on affect in boiler-plating cost as well

Comment: `and restore it if user need to restore the default values. for example settings.` This is the wrong way to think about it. If you want to use the default settings, delete the saved entries from the database. Then `new` up the class again. **Boom** - all of the defaults will be magically there.

Comment: I am saying it doesn't _need_ to be `static`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/uU3l7v The answers below are clever, but possibly over-engineered. Use the right tool (i.e. not a static class) and everything will just work.

Comment: There is no built-in language feature to do what you want, and not in one line. My solution at least gives you a one-liner at the call site, and was in fact inspired by *you* doing the research into a method I didn't know existed :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. For instance property, just new an instance then get the default property value is the easiest way.
2. For static property, the default value can be preserved in the static constructor.

```
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static int MyProp1 { get; set; } = 100;
        public static bool MyProp2 { get; set; } = false;

        private static Dictionary<string, object> defaultValues;

        static MyClass()
        {
            defaultValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach(var prop in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            {
                defaultValues[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(null);
            }
        }

        public static (T,bool) GetDefault<T>(string propName)
        {
            if(defaultValues.TryGetValue(propName, out object value))
            {
                return ((T)(value), true);
            }
            return (default, false);
        }
    }

    //test codes
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        MyClass.MyProp1 = 1000;
        MyClass.MyProp2 = true;

        var defaultValueOrProp1 = MyClass.GetDefault<int>("MyProp1");
        if(defaultValueOrProp1.Item2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(defaultValueOrProp1.Item1);//100
        }

        var defaultValueOrProp2 = MyClass.GetDefault<bool>("MyProp2");
        if (defaultValueOrProp2.Item2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(defaultValueOrProp2.Item1);//false
        }
    }
```

**Following Line added by question author:**

For setting property with default value

```
private static void ResetPropertyValue(string PropertyName)
{ 
    typeof(Options).GetProperty(PropertyName).SetValue(null, 
    defaultValues[PropertyName]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is best reflection one.

Comment: @deveton Thank you, this is the best encouragement for me to answer questions.

Answer (score 5):

Properties are little more then Syntax sugar for get/set function pairs. And what you got there is little more then a basic, bog-standart assignment/function call around when the constructor runs. As all literals and constatns, it should no longer *exist* at runtime.

The naive way would be to have a constant like `IsSoundEffectsDefaultValue`. And I do think that is sufficient in most cases.

There is a off-chance that a old idea of mine might apply to your broader problem. I need to search for the code however.

**Edit:**

I could not find my old code, unfortunately. I can re-create it however. The basic idea is to have multiple "layers" of values, with one value hiding (but not overwriting) the other.

```
public class defaultAble<T>{
    readonly T defaultValue;

    //constructor
    public defaultAble(T defaultValue){
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        //First set the value
        RestoreDefault();
    }

    public RestoreDefault(){
        value = this.defaultValue;
    }

    public T value { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

There might be a even better solution in WPF/MVVM circles. A lot of MVVM is writing properties with the same code - one that raises change notification by INotifyPropertyChanged. And a big issue with Properties is not writing the backing field by accident.

Some people figured out solutions like putting the actuall value and all the code into a something like a `Dictionar<string, object>` mostly automagically. I am not sure about the details, however. Also DependancyProperties might get close to it too.

Comment: hmmm. its good solution but declares 40 constants for 40 properties will not be cute ^^  is there something like Type.GetProperty().DefaultValue .... oh

Comment: @deveton the answer is no.

Comment: TheGeneral, what you will do so if you have same situation. restoring default values. depending on example user click button and then restoring 40 properties. what your solution can you tell.

Comment: @deveton "Cuteness" is not a factor we consider in Programming. It working is the first requirement. It being readable the second. It needing little write work the thrid. Cuteness? Not even on the list.

Comment: but 40 constants and 40 properties will not readable. what about multiplying this by 4 later. Anyway, it looks like your solution is good. which the best. i was thinking about dictionary<string,object>... but never got constants in my head.

Comment: @deveton: Updated my answer. my best idea is to pack this mechanic into a very simple class. | But I think the bigger problem is that you have **40** settings. Not that you have 40 **settings**.

Comment: what about something that i can't run till now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getconstantvalue?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @deveton Huh? I was not even aware this thing existed. No idea how exactly it works either. Reflection depends entirely on wich of those strings and literals were put into the MSIL for it to retreive. | It is also reflection. Reflection is a good fall back. But it should only ever be used as a fallback too. But you propably want to use it to itterate over the settings anyway?

Answer (score 4):

One approach you could use would be based on Custom Attributes. You could define as Custom Attribute to hold the default value. For example,

```
public class DefaultValueAttribute:Attribute
{
    public object DefaultValue{get;set;}
    public DefaultValueAttribute(object defaultValue)=>DefaultValue = defaultValue;
}
```

You can now use the Attribute to store the default value as

```
public static class SomeClass
{
  [DefaultValueAttribute(true)]
  public static bool IsSoundEffects { get; set; } = true;
}
```

For retrieving the same, you could depend on reflection.

```
var defaultValue = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty(nameof(SomeClass.IsSoundEffects), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                                .GetCustomAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>().DefaultValue;
```

Making the reflection call a generic method to be used with other properties.

```
public T GetDefaultValue<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var result = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty(nameof(SomeClass.IsSoundEffects), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                                .GetCustomAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>().DefaultValue;

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(result,typeof(T));
}
```

Usage

```
var defaultValue = GetDefaultValue<bool>(nameof(SomeClass.IsSoundEffects));
```

Answer (score 3):

> **OP**: I filling the properties from the database. and restore it if user
>   need to restore the default values.
>
> This post tries to answer based on based on above requirement which you mentioned in the question.(Not based on the question title.)

**Option 1 - Using System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue**

On of the standard solutions for setting default value for properties, is using [`DefaultValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) attribute of the .NET Framework. [You can see](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/DefaultValueAttribute.cs,88c0ebe7d8011a51,references) this pattern in a lot of classes in .NET Framework. For example:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)]
public static bool MyProperty{ get; set; } = true;
```

Then .NET Framework gives you the reset functionality by [`PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.resetvalue?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["MyProperty"].ResetValue(this);
```

**Option 2 - Create a static Default instance**

You can have a static default instance of the class and use it for resetting properties.

If you want to have the default instance as `private` you can keep it as a single instance field.

If you want the default instance as `public` you need to create a property and return a new instance in the getter.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly MyClass Default = new MyClass();
    //OR
    //public static MyClass Default { get { return new MyClass(); } }

    public bool MyProperty{ get; set; } = true;
    public void Reset()
    {
        this.MyProperty = Default.MyProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the MyClass is static in my case. because it contains globals? so the Default instance can't created from the static class.

Comment: If your class is just a container for some methods (like `System.Math`) it's fine to keep it `static`, otherwise I suggest you make it an instance class. And for the properties, Instead of creating static properties, I suggest creating an interface, then implement the interface by your class and inject the class using DI or a ServiceLocator. This way, today you implement the class in a way which stores properties in DB, tomorrow you implement a different storage mechanism. In addition, it gives to another option for default values. You can create a public immutable `Default` as well.

Comment: I never know about DI or ServiceLocator. please if you never mind gave an example of it or more tips. :)

Comment: It's too broad for this answer. I may propose some readings for you in the comments. But in general I would advise you start by reading about SOLID principles.

Comment: I'd say start by SOLID, then after you read about D, read about DI (dependency injection).

Answer (score 2):

Use [PropertyInfo.GetConstantValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getconstantvalue?view=netframework-4.8).

Consider your class

```
class YourClass
{
    public static bool IsSoundEffects { get; set; } = true;   // C# 6.0 allows this
}
```

and consider a "getter" class you create

```
class DefaultGetter
{
    T GetDefault<TClass, TProp>(string propertyName) where T : new()
    {        
        if (!defaults.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var defaultValues)
            if (!defaultValues.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var value))
            {
                 // reflect on prototype getting all the PropertyInfo
                 // and store them in the dictionary of dictionaries
                 // then assign to value...
                 defaults[typeof(TClass)] = defaultValues = typeof(TClass).GetProperties().Select(x => new { x.Name, Value = x.GetConstantValue() }).ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
            }

            value = defaultValues[propertyName]
        }

        return (TProp)value;
    }

    IDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, object> defaults = new ... // elided for brevity
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
var defaultIsSoundEffects = defaultGetter.GetDefault<YourClass, bool>("IsSoundEffects");
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use following approaches**

1. using constants which is good if no need to change variables after initializations.
2. use static readonly if only variable can changed in cosntructor.
3. use dictionary with